# How to parse DateTime from string

Tags: vb.net, datetime

When reading DateTime from excel, the result day and month are being read as dd MM, while the excel content was according to MM dd style.

S1 contains:    "12/09/2017"

The code:

```
Dim t_from As DateTime
t_from = CDate(s1)
```

t_from includes Sep as a month, instead of Dec as should be.

I also tried:

```
Dim b As Boolean = DateTime.TryParseExact(s1,                                  "MM/dd/yy",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,dt)
```

this code fails  (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime)

How can I convert the text to DateTime VB variable, according to month first (before date)?

Comment: Why you are not trying using moment.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt" should parse correctly dates from the excel

```
Dim parsedDate As Date
Date.TryParseExact(
    "9/12/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt",
    Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    parsedDate)

parsedDate.ToString() ' 12.09.2017 00:00:00
```

For "12/09/2017" where 12 is a month and 09 is a day use format: "MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: I made a mistake in the question. s1 string content is  "12/09/2017" only (just date, no time). Still I would expect your code to work, yet it returns false.